# For every 1 you have in this value, it adds 1 to this value. How do I do it?

Tags: lua, luau

I want to make a simple calculator type thing.
Without doing a bunch of elseif statements.

```
value2 = 1
value1 = 1 + math.random(1, 20)
```

for every 1 you have in value1, it adds 1 to value2.

Comment: So what have you tried so far and what were your results ? Can you give an example of your input, logic and output?

Answer (score 0):

```
math.randomseed(os.time())
local value1 = 1 + math.random(1, 20)
```

> for every 1 you have in value1, it adds 1 to value2.

`value1` has `1 + math.random(1,20)` ones. If you add one 1 to value2 for every 1 in value1 you simply add value1 to value2.

Assume math.random returns 5, value1 is 6. There's 6 1s in 6 so you add 6 to value2 resulting in a total of 7 1s.

```
local value2 = 1 + value1
```

Not sure how this request makes any sense but that's what you asked for.